# Keep url parameters after clicking <h:commandButton>

Tags: jsf, seam

I've got a page which takes an id as a url parameter and uses it to get an object and display data about it.  On this page we've got a modal which includes a file upload component, so we cannot use ajax to process the save.  Instead we do this:

```
    <rich:modalPanel domElementAttachment="parent" id="profilePanel" styleClass="popUp" resizeable="false" moveable="false" autosized="true" zindex="200" top="-10">
        <a4j:form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="profilePanelFormId">
            <q:box title="Edit Advocacy Profile" width="width6x" wantFocus="true">
                <s:div id="profilePanelForm">
                    <rich:messages rendered="#{messagesUtil.errorsExist}"/>
                    <a4j:include viewId="/panel/advocacy/advocateProfileEdit.xhtml"/>
                </s:div>
                <h:commandButton id="cancel" immediate="true" value="Cancel" action="#{advocateManager.cancelEditCommitment}" styleClass="button cancel" tabindex="100"/>
                <h:commandButton id="save" value="Save" action="#{advocateManager.saveCommitment}" styleClass="submit" tabindex="101"/>
            </q:box>
        </a4j:form>
    </rich:modalPanel>
```

We populate the parameter in pages.xml like so:

```
<page view-id="/advocacy/advocateCommitmentView.xhtml" login-required="true">
    <param name="confirmationCode" value="#{advocateManager.commitmentId}"/>
</page>
```

So far so good.  The problem we're running into is when a user clicks save or cancel the url gets rewritten without the necessary id parameter.  If the user then refreshes the page it throws errors because it doesn't have this key.  Does anyone know how I can call my save method without using ajax and still keep the url parameter or intercept the call and add the parameter back in?

Answer (score 1):

Put `?includeViewParams=true` at the end of the action string.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because `<h:commandButton/>` posts the form, and form posts do not include parameters in the URL. To add the parameters, create a navigation rule that redirects to the same page:

```
<navigation from-action="#{advocateManager.saveCommitment}">
    <rule>
        <redirect view-id="/same-page.xhtml" />
    </rule>
</navigation>
```

When doing the redirect, page parameters are encoded and added to the URL. Note that this requires that `#{advocateManager.commitmentId}` is populated when the redirect is done.